# PyCharm CE and Auto-run

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Sorry for the newbie question.

I am running PyCharm CE and would like to have my project run at a specific time every day, say 4 am local time but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how, if at all possible to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You expect pycharm to do this?  Generally pycharm is for developing, not for deploying.  Are you thinking that pycharm will be doing something that would not be done simply by running the script?

Answer (score 0):

1. First download [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/)
2. Second open up the terminal and use `pip install schedule`
3. Now you will be able to use the [schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) library
4. The schedule library will allow you to run a function everyday